# Azure Data Factory (Graph Data Connect/Office365 Linked Service): how to work with Binary sink dataset?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Here's what I'm doing.
My company needs me to dump all group members and their corresponding groups into an SQL database.  Power Automate takes forever with too many loops and API calls...so I'm trying Data Factory for the first time.
Using the Office365 Linked Service, we can get all organization members--but the only compatible sink option is Azure Blob storage (or DataLake) because the sink MUST be binary.
Ok, fine.  So we got a Azure Blob storage account configured and set up.

But now that the pipeline 'copy data' has completed (after 4 hours?), I don't know what to do with this binary data.  There seems to be no function, method or dataflow option to interpret the binary data as JSON, delimited text, or otherwise.  The storage account shows 1042 different blobs, ranging haphazardly from a few kilobytes to dozens of megabytes (why???).  Isn't there anything in Data Factory that can interpret this binary data and allow me to dump the columns I need into SQL?

I was able to load the blob data into Power Automate and parse it into usable JSON using the base64 and json functions, but this is robbing Peter to pay Paul because I have to us a loop to load the contents of 1042 different blobs and I'm exceeding our bandwidth quota.  Besides that, some of the contents of the blobs are empty!! (again...why??)

I've looked everywhere for answers, no luck.  So thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use Binary dataset in `Copy activity`, `GetMetadata activity`, or
> `Delete activity`. When using Binary dataset, the service does not parse
> file content but treat it as-is.

So, The `data flow activity` which is used to transform the data in Azure Data Factory isn't supported for Binary dataset.

Hence, you can use Azure Service for another approach like Azure Databricks in which you can use Python OpenCV or any other Data Engineering library in preferred programming language.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know if it's normal for a blob binary dataset to be in 100's of chunks after a single pipeline run? 
I'm sure I can figure out how to use Azure Function or Azure Databricks.  If you have any suggestions where to learn what I am trying to do, I would appreciate it.
I tried to upvote but I am too new, so thanks again!